# Graph decomposition into product of two graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the following graph $G(n,k)$, where $n$ denotes the number of rays and $k$ is the length of each ray (see fig. for the example with $n=k=3$)

[image]

I look for a possibility to represent graph of such type, $G(n,k)$, as the product of two graph, $S_n$ and $P_{k-1}$, where $S_n$ is the star graph with $n$ rays and $P_{k-1}$ is the chain of $k-1$ length.

I have checked definitions of different forms of graph product from Wiki but all of them seem unappropriate for my goal. In addition, I am not sure that it is possible to decompose my graph $G(n,k)$ into desired product.

Comment: What is your motivation for representing $G(n,k)$ in this way? What properties would you like this graph product notion to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be possible for any definition of product I'm familiar with, and won't work for any product whose vertex set is the cartesian product $V(P_{k-1})\times V(S_n)$.

To see this, note that your graph has $n\cdot(k-1)+1$ vertices, while any product whose vertex set is a cartesian product will have $(n+1)\dot k$ vertices, which is a fair bit bigger.

If you want a `nice' description of $G(n,k)$, you could call it the $k$-fold [subdivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#) of $S_n$, or the disjoint union of $n$ $P_{k-1}$ paths, all of which have an end vertex identified.

Comment: Good answer. I would rather call it *wedge sum of paths*, as disjoint union with identification sounds a bit odd to me...

Comment: You have to be clear what your `basepoint' for a wedge sum is though, so you end up describing the identification anyhow :P